# firebase storage how to dispaly image

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm trying to fetch images out of firebase storage with url and `Image.network()`.

But somehow I stuck.

I use this example from firebase storage documentation:

```
   Future downloadURLExample() async {
   String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref('users/123/avatar.jpg')
      .getDownloadURL();

  // Within your widgets:
  // Image.network(downloadURL);
return downloadURL;

}
```

But I dont know how do I get this String downloadURL into my container and Image.network.

I try to do it like this:

```
Container(
 width: 200,
 height: 200,
 child: Image.network(downloadURL),
),
```

But it doesnt work. What am I missing?

Comment: You can not display from local variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to get `downloadURL` which is not in the [scope](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lexical-scope) of the build method. You need to get the download URL from the `downloadURLExample` method.

Here is an example using [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  Future<String> _downloadURLFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _downloadURLFuture = downloadURLExample();    
  }

  Future<String> downloadURLExample() async {
    String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('users/123/avatar.jpg').getDownloadURL();
    return downloadURL;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _downloadURLFuture, 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final String downloadURL = snapshot.data;
            return Image.network(
              downloadURL,
              loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );                  
              },
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it's a good example, thank you, now I know hwat I was missing. Do you know how to use `CircularProgressIndicator()` to display while image is downloading. In you example it only shows the indacator when complete data is missing. But there is data, just not complete yet. I checked it with print statements.

Comment: Yeah, you can set the `loadingBuilder` property of `Image.network` to display the progress indicator. I've updated my answer to show that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// use firebase package as fb
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  //variable for the called photo uri
  Uri img;
  //
  downloadURLExample() {
    fb
        .storage()
        .refFromURL(
            'gs://******.appspot.com/users/123/avatar.jpg')
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((value) => setState(() => img = value));
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    //initialize method
    downloadURLExample();
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  img == null
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              child: Image.network(img.toString()),
          
    );
  }
}
```